# automatic word wrapping in Labels?

Tags: address-labels

is there a possibility to activate automatic word wrapping in Labels? If a Name to long actually it dont break the line.

Civi 4.6 Drupal

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with CSS. For a text element to wrap, it needs to have a width set. Something like:

```
.crm-event-label {
        width: 500px;
}
```

(To include Custom CSS, point to a .css file via Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs)